What example URLs can be used to fetch from browsers without having CORS error?
Even Example Domain yields CORS error on browser:
fetch('https://example.com').then(console.log).catch(console.error)

// Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://example.com/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.
// TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. 

Are there any example domains that I can try on browsers?

Your example doesn't really make sense. Have a look at the mdn fetch example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

I don't see any problem? I can run that successfully with localhost. Do you mean it's because I use promise instead of await?


example.com is not intended to serve e.g as a API. 2. What should console.log return without any arguments? - a text or JSON? So you can use any URL that allows cross-origin access so has suitable CORS header. If not you're out of luck at least with JS. With server-side languages like php you may use e.g CURL calls


A client can send a simple cross-origin request (though not read its response) without the need for CORS. Sending any other cross-origin request (and reading its response) requires the server to be configured CORS. As for same-origin requests, they typically don't involve CORS; however, with the advent of Private Network Access, even some same-origin requests can give rise to CORS preflight.
